# Visual Studio Code for Mac as diff/merge tool in Sourcetree

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way that I can set Visual Studio Code as the default diff/merge tool in Sourcetree on Mac?

Comment: The built-in `opendiff` tool on a Mac is very nice, btw. Just run `opendiff file1 file2` from Terminal.

Answer (score 22):

You need to do below configuration in Sourcetree

- Go to Sourcetree → **Preferences** → **Diff**
- In the section **External Diff / Merge**, select **Custom** for the **Visual Diff Tool** and **Merge Tool**
- **Diff** Arguments →
  `--diff --wait "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"`
- **Merge** Arguments → `-n --wait "$MERGED"`
- After configuration is saved, then goto the Sourcetree and right click on the file with merge conflicts **Resolve Conflicts** → **Launch External Merge Tool**

> Note: **Diff** and **Merge** command should point to `/usr/local/bin/code` and not `code` otherwise it will not work

[image: Sourcetree external diff/merge tool configuration] 
[image: Step to resolve conflict in source tree]

Comment: May also need to add `code` to your path
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation I found](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-external-diff-tool/qaq-p/35047), Sourcetree just uses whatever you've configured your Git repository to use.

You can configure your Git repository to use Visual Studio Code with the `git config` command like so:

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

However, you must configure Visual Studio Code to [launch from the terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) before this will work.

See [this blog post](https://blog.soltysiak.it/en/2017/01/set-visual-studio-code-as-default-git-editor-and-diff-tool/) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Setup-Sourcetree-to-use-Visual-Studio-Code-as-External-Diff/qaq-p/685939) with instructions on how to get it to work on the Mac. I wasn't able to get it to work until I used the full path to the code executable (I also set code in my global path)

```
/usr/local/bin/code
```